# Is it logical to calculate zscore for list A using the standard deviation and mean from list B?

Tags: statistics

I am working on an application where we collect the total income of a household. We have a $3^{rd}$ party integration which provides us the household income estimates. I have calculated standard deviation and mean for both these datasets. To compare how many standard deviations away the $3^{rd}$ party integration data is from my collected income (or vice-versa), I am planning on calculating the z-score as follows:

```
z-score = (list_income_collected - mean_of_3rd_party_income_estimates)/ 
           standard_deviation_of_3rd_party_income_estimates
```

Is it logically sound?